# Web API RegisterExternal login with Facebook - modelstate is invalid resulting in an internal error 500

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, facebook-login, restful-authentication

I am trying to get login/create with Facebook to work. My setup is I have an ASP.NET Web API 2.0 and an Xamarin app.

I have gotten most to work, but only my `api/Account/RegisterExternal` fails because my ModelState is false and therefore throwing an error 500.

**My progress:**

1) In the app, I call the providers URL (`Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true`) and redirect the user in web view inside my app to the Facebook link.

2) The users logs in, and I get the response back in the form off:

```
http://api.domain.com/#access_token=V_Jxfx13g2bU16sCJ3x3PzsKED4v8SFii-Yxco-39wHL9vVn8A5VF21c7fPbzV3F-ZZnPazg-J0coUL8jDeR6dKCx1NodAWZVdv24sUzSH5GanM367I5ITIdg0nUjsUjJg_twYAtJonOMwZDSpRlGh3n9eC9hm7ucy-dFtCvuoREHAhd9tCP0TdVMV_pH7doq5maaOLvm3uRImFLoEFue1Gr3ixIpLRerdGK4VV5I_eW4HOKgT7I9wOi0e0WKHBVgcfVUqnBuoIAtUQgj8HC1r9OF0lIQq0gFFdWRWfwCv6N_rJT7LhUIKWR7z6YeTQCQomOg-TbGm-dSZjxDabq2SYLN-yigigKqOtIUWM5ZaM&token_type=bearer&expires_in=7776000&state=R0X6fOvVLZPTU8S2F49EE9bfJWo4z_qihxE8dyQ59221
```

3) I now take this token, and run the following code to register the user where I have added the token as "Bearer":

```
    public async Task RegisterExternalUser(RegisterBindingModel registration, string token)
    {
        var url = GetUrl("Account/RegisterExternal");
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(registration);
        var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var result = await _client.PostAsync(url, data);
    }
```

However, when this hits my default account controller code, it results in the internal error we see here:

```
 [OverrideAuthentication]
 [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]
 [Route("api/account/RegisterExternal")]
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RegisterExternal(RegisterExternalBindingModel model)
 {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var info = await Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }

        // more default code
 }
```

Any idea what is going wrong here? :-)

**EDIT:**

**1) Adding registerexternalbindingmodel per request:**

```
public class RegisterExternalBindingModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**2) I found out what's breaking my model**

After playing around with the viewmodel, it turns out it's the following attribute that makes my model invalid:

```
   [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]
```

I could of course just remove it, but it doesn't change that then:

```
   var info = await Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

Becomes null.

Comment: can u pls place the code of  RegisterExternalBindingModel ?

Comment: @FakeisMe done:)

Comment: is the required field having value when it hits the action ? because what will be happening is RegisterBindingModel  [which will be in json string] will get deserialised to  RegisterExternalBindingModel  so at that time the Email value should get mapped .

Comment: @FakeisMe Um, we create the account in this call so we need it when we run the "more default code" part of my code snippet above. But I can try to remove the required part - would that help you think?

Comment: since the Email field  is marked as 'Required' a value is required to make the model valid. You can remove the Required attribute and check.

Comment: @FakeisMe Turns out the problem is in the attribute and not the model. Have you seen this before?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156911/discussion-between-fakeisme-and-lars-holdgaard).